# Selenium test can't click on mat-select element

Tags: c#, selenium, angular-material

Angular Material Select (`mat-select`) inside Form Field (`mat-form-field`) ignores Selenium click

[image: DOM part]

When test runs, dropdown doesn't appear after click is made by Selenium. If it is made manually by me, test continues and passes.
I also tried to use SelectElement class but it's not applicable since mat-select doesn't use any select elements

public class Page definition:

```
[FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//*[@id='form']//mat-form-field//*[@class='mat-form-field-flex' and .//*[@formcontrolname='network']]")] // also tried all surrounding elements from DOM including mat-form-field and mat-select (look at attached screenshot)
public IWebElement _formNetworkFormControl;

public bool IsFormNetworkFormControlComponentPresent()
{
    return ExtendedWebElementOperations.IsElementDisplayed(_formNetworkFormControl);
}

// Click dropdown
public void ClickFormNetworkFormControl(IWebDriver webdriver)
{
    // Wait is needed until data is loaded and select is enabled
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(_formNetworkFormControl));

    _formNetworkFormControl.Click();
}

// To select option after dropdown click
public void SelectByOptionName(IWebDriver webdriver, string optionName)
{
    string xpath = $"//mat-option[span[text()[contains(.,'{optionName}')]]]";
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
    wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementIsVisible(By.XPath(xpath)));

    IWebElement optionNameSelect = webdriver.FindElement(By.XPath(xpath));

    optionNameSelect.Click();
}
```

Test:

```
var testedPage = new Page(Driver);

testedPage.ClickAddRingTestFormNetworkFormControl(Driver); // click is made but dropdown doesn't appear
testedPage.SelectByOptionName(Driver, networkName); // if select is clicked manually, this works great
```

Comment: Have you tried using javascript to send the click to that element? (I don't know how to do that in C#)

Comment: @BreaksSoftware I used Selenium IDE to record this test and it showed me that desirable action is `click` on any element from `.mat-form-field-infix` to `mat-select > .mat-select-trigger > .mat-select-value > span`, but required listener is assigned to `.mat-form-field-flex`. But click on any of those elements does neither invoke its own listeners nor bubble event up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `mat-select` has `aria-disabled='true'` until required data is loaded, so

```
wait.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable(_formNetworkFormControl));
```

doesn't cover this case.

I fixed it with updating Page class following way:

```
public IWebElement IsElementHasTrueAriaDisabledAttribute(IWebDriver webdriver, IWebElement element)
{
    if (element.GetAttribute("aria-disabled").Equals("false"))
    {
        return element;
    }

    return null;
}

public void ClickFormNetworkFormControl(IWebDriver webdriver)
{
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(webdriver, timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
    wait.Until<IWebElement>((d) => 
    {
        return IsElementHasTrueAriaDisabledAttribute(d, _formNetworkFormControl);
    });

    _formNetworkFormControl.Click();
}
```